# How to store a distance matrix in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, matrix, distance

What is the best way to store a distance matrix in mysql?

Currently I have two tables:

`tPlaces`

`PlaceID`, `PlaceName`, `Location`

`tDistances`

`PlaceID_1`, `PlaceID_2`, `Distance`

Is this the best way to go about it, I have heard of `RTREE` and `BTREE` but haven't found a comprehensive guide on how to implement such a soltuion.

Comment: The suggestion in your question is better than the two answers (sofar) Don't forget the keys: for tPlaces, all three fields are candidate keys, for tDistances the tPlaces_[12] are both FK to tPlaces. The index for location is difficult: some platforms have special 2D "GIS" table types for it, for simple databases you could index on *both* {x,y} and {y,x}

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that anything but a pure string would be feasible. This way you would be able to write a simple method in PHP (or whatever you might use) to process the data. I would store it in

```
ID | matrix
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | "PlaceID, PlaceName, Location, PlaceID_1, PlaceID_2, Distance"
2  | "PlaceID, PlaceName, Location, PlaceID_1, PlaceID_2, Distance"
3  | "PlaceID, PlaceName, Location, PlaceID_1, PlaceID_2, Distance"
```

You can process the data by using [str.explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSON.stringify() you can store the entire result as a string exactly how you recieved it.